# nuxt.js passing prop to component's inner element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a simple component:

```
<template>
    <div id="search__index_search-form">
        <input :foo-id="fooId" @keyup.enter="findFoos()" type="text" :value="keyword" @input="updateKeyword"
               placeholder="Search for a foo">
        <button @click="findFoos()">Search!</button>
        {{fooId}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapState} from "vuex";

    export default {
        computed: mapState({
            keyword: state => state.search.keyword
        }),
        data: function () {
            return {fooId: "all"};
        },
        methods: {
            updateKeyword(e) {
                this.$store.commit("setSearchKeyword", e.target.value);
            },
            findFoos() {
                this.$store.dispatch("findFoos");
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am calling it from nuxt page:

```
<template>
    <searchbar v-bind:fooId="500"/>
</template>
<script>
    import searchBar from "~/components/search-bar.vue";

    export default {
        components: {
            'searchbar': searchBar
        }
    };
</script>
```

This results in:

```
<div id="search__index_search-form" fooid="500"><input shop-id="all" type="text" placeholder="Search for a foo"><button>Search!</button>
      all
</div>
```

Question is, why is fooId bound to "div.search__index_search-form" and not to input? And how come {{fooId}} results in "all" (default state), and not "500"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fooId` is rendered on `div#search__index_search-form` because you do not declare `fooId` as a property of the component. Vue's default behavior is to render undeclared properties on the root element of the component.

You need to declare `fooId` as a property.

```
 export default {
    props: {
      fooId: {type: String, default: "all"}
    },
    computed: mapState({
        keyword: state => state.search.keyword
    }),
    methods: {
        updateKeyword(e) {
            this.$store.commit("setSearchKeyword", e.target.value);
        },
        findProducts() {
            this.$store.dispatch("findFoos");
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure what you are really trying to accomplish though.

```
<input :foo-id="fooId" ... >
```

That bit of code doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Thanks, declaring it as a prop was the solution.

Comment: Very good solution. Also describing the default. I did not know about that nice!